# Convert -WebKit-filter Sepia value into PHP GD Sepia

Tags: php, css, gd, imagefilter

With CSS3 you can set Sepia using the -webkit-filter

example:

```
-webkit-filter: sepia(55%);
```

The fiter takes a value between 0% and 100%.

With PHP I see most people use the following bit of code to apply sepia filter

```
 imagefilter($img,IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE,100,50,0);
```

Which accepts 3 values.

How can I convert the CSS Sepia filter value to a value which can be used to create the filter effect using PHP GD?

Comment: PHP => Serverside, CSS => Clientside. The imagefilter function just simulates a sepia effect by applying a brownish color.

Comment: Oliver I know that. I let the user change the Sepia effect on the Clientside then when they want to save or share the image I send it the server to make the change permanent.

Comment: Hey @PhilipKirkbride did you ever find a decent way to replicate CSS sepia filter with PHP GD? I'm trying to accomplish same thing thanks!